# Installing Lubuntu 14.04 on an HP Omnibook 6100

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install Lubuntu 14.04 on an HP Omnibook with a Pentium 3 and 384MB of RAM and 10GB HDD, I would like to know if it is possible to install this new versions on old computers or I would have to install an old non-PAE version of Ubuntu, I can install via the alternative Ubuntu install or Core install, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) documentation recommends minimum memory of 128 MB for operation although they indicate that it might be a little slow

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu  I think you are not correct, please answer with helpful answers: System Requirements

A Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MB of RAM is probably a bottom-line configuration that may yield slow yet usable system with a standard lubuntu desktop.

Comment: @Brask:  Updated my post - apologies for answering too quickly.